# Is @staticmethod decorator needed for declaring a Static Method in Python?

Tags: python, oop, static-methods

I am curious about why we need the `@staticmethod` decorator to declare method as static.

I was reading about static methods in Python, and I came to know that a static method can be callable without instantiating its class.

So I tried the two examples below, but both do the same:

```
class StatMethod:
  def stat():
    print("without Decorator")

class StatMethod_with_decorator:
  @staticmethod
  def stat():
    print("With Decorator")
```

If I call the `stat()` method on the class directly, both print/show the values below:

```
>> StatMethod.stat()
without Decorator
>> StatMethod_with_decorator.stat()
With Decorator
```

Comment: Now try it with a function that takes some arguments...

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/136097/what-is-the-difference-between-staticmethod-and-classmethod-in-python

Comment: Note that I've found out with some tests that Python 2.7 requires using the decorator when the function has an arg, whereas Python 3 does not. Python 2.7 tries to match the first arg to the instance (it thinks it's self), whereas Python 3 seems to understand that one arg is just the function's arg, without having to use the annotation for that. I haven't found anything about this specific difference in the docs.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

You need the decorator if you intend to try to call the `@staticmethod` from the instance of the class instead of of the class directly

```
class Foo():
    def bar(x):
        return x + 5

>>> f = Foo()
>>> f.bar(4)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#7>", line 1, in <module>
    f.bar(4)
TypeError: bar() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Now if I declare `@staticmethod` the `self` argument isn't passed implicitly as the first argument

```
class Foo():
    @staticmethod
    def bar(x):
        return x + 5

>>> f = Foo()
>>> f.bar(4)
9
```

Comment: Do you know if there is an established or agreed-upon term to refer to static methods that you can _only_ invoke through the class name directly? Or does the community simply call both "static methods"? Any connection to perhaps how these terms are used in Java, C# or elsewhere? Also, what would you say is their primary purpose vs static methods defined with the decorator?

Comment: So, when we only would use the method via the class and not via an instance object, then @staticmethod is optional?

Comment: This is a good answer but the use of *foo* and *bar* makes this unnecessarily hard to understand. Descriptive variables help in examples, too. Not just production code.

Comment: @problemofficer-n.f.Monica I get your point but fwiw those are canonically the placeholder class/function/variable names when providing examples. In this case I think it does not detract from the point I am trying to make in my answer in any meaningful way.

Comment: *Foo* has semantics attached to it, it is a class. *bar* has semantics attached to it, it is a method of that class. I disagree that it is "canonical" because that term implies an authority or best-practice consensus. *Foo* and *bar* IMHO are merely remnants of an older age, where people did not understand the importance of descriptive variables. I heard your argument several times and think this is a [Appeal to tradition logical fallacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appeal_to_tradition)

Comment: Python... Oh Python... Yet another example of the mess it is

Comment: So, can we use this correct answer as a guide for how to create a singleton in Python? I see a lot of effort to do this here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6760685/creating-a-singleton-in-python but I wonder why not just  use a class with static methods that are not decorated. This way, if someone does instantiate this Singleton and tries to call a static method on the object (not on the class), it will error, which would be desired.

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#types) describes some transformations that are done when calling a user defined method:

> Note that the transformation from function object to (unbound or
>   bound) method object happens each time the attribute is retrieved from
>   the class or instance. In some cases, a fruitful optimization is to
>   assign the attribute to a local variable and call that local variable.
>   Also notice that this transformation only happens for user-defined
>   functions; other callable objects (and all non-callable objects) are
>   retrieved without transformation. It is also important to note that
>   user-defined functions which are attributes of a class instance are
>   not converted to bound methods; this only happens when the function is
>   an attribute of the class.

For methods marked as staticmethod this is different:

> Static method objects provide a way of defeating the transformation of
>   function objects to method objects described above. A static method
>   object is a wrapper around any other object, usually a user-defined
>   method object. When a static method object is retrieved from a class
>   or a class instance, the object actually returned is the wrapped
>   object, which is not subject to any further transformation. Static
>   method objects are not themselves callable, although the objects they
>   wrap usually are. Static method objects are created by the built-in
>   staticmethod() constructor.

Answer (score 0):

if function has some parameters, then call non static method would be failed

and static method didn't use the local variables in the class, but the class method will be

Comment: for python 3 even with sone parameters the call of the static method would work (not fail)

Answer (score -1):

Update: In python 3.10 you dont need the decorator any more

Comment: But i got same error with below code in python 3.10 in second print statement using an instance   `class test(): 
    def func(arg1, arg2):  print('func')

print(test.func(5, 'arg2'))
s = test()
print(s.func(5, 'arg2'))`

Answer (score -3):

Just my simple approach here. Forget the decorators. Use the class directly (Python 3.8):

```
class MyClass:
    def myMethod(self, myValue):
        print(myValue)

MyClass.myMethod(None, "hi")
```

Or both:

```
MyClass.myMethod(None, "hi from class")
myInstance = myClass()
myInstance.myMethod2("hi from instance")
```

Comment: I would consider it an anti-pattern to accept an argument to a method if you do not intend to use it. So in this case accepting `self` but not using it falls into that category. It would therefore be canonical to make that method static.