# Why is a method of a Python class declared without "self" and without decorators not raising an exception?

Tags: python, class, methods, static-methods, class-method

I thought that the following code would result in an error because as far as I have read, a method in a Python class must either have "self" (or any other label, but "self" by convention) as its first argument, or "cls" or similar if the `@classmethod` decorator is used, or none if the `@staticmethod` decorator is used.

How come I get no error running this with Python 3.5 in the Terminal, even though `test_method` does not meet these requirements? It seems to work fine as a static method, but without the decorator.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys

class MyClass:

    def test_method(args):
        print(args[1])

    @staticmethod
    def static_method():
        print("static_method")

    @classmethod
    def class_method(cls):
        print("class_method")


def main(args):
    MyClass.test_method(args)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
```

Output:

```
$ python3 testscript.py "testing"
$ testing
```

**EDIT**:

My question could also be phrased differently, drawing attention away from `self` and to `@staticmethod`: "How come I'm getting a seemingly working static method without the @staticmethod decorator?"

Comment: Short answer is: it's not a method until you create an instance of the class. It's simply a function. Try MyClass().text_method('test') and you will get an error.

Comment: @Jblasco If it is not a method but simply a function, how is it different from a static method declared with the decorator?

Comment: Perhaps this question answers , your [query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43587044/do-we-really-need-staticmethod-decorator-in-python-to-declare-static-method)

Comment: A method will be accesible from an instance of the class, @Theod'Or. In other words, this cannot be used from an instance, only from the class itself.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In Python 2, functions defined in a class body are automatically converted to "unbound methods", and cannot be called directly without a staticmethod decorator. In Python 3, this concept was removed; `MyClass.text_method` is a simple function that lives inside the MyClass namespace, and can be called directly.

The main reason to still use `staticmethod` in Python 3 is if you also want to call the method on an *instance*. If you don't use the decorator, the method will always be passed the instance as the first parameter, causing a TypeError.

Comment: I've accepted this answer because it makes the distinction between Python 2 and 3 clear. It's really what was throwing me, I did not know this change had taken place (not been using Python for a while). Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by "can be called directly"? That I don't have to create an object of type `MyClass` first on which I will call `text_method()`?

Comment: Yes, call with MyClass.text_method(...).

Answer (score 6):

There is nothing special about this. In python 3 there is no difference between a function defined inside a class or a function defined outside a class. Both of them are normal functions.

The `self` that you are talking about here or maybe `cls` comes into picture only when you access the function through an **instance**. Hence here you didn't get any error.

However if you modify your code just a little bit to look like the following, then you'd get an error that you expected.

```
def main(args):
    MyClass().test_method(args)
    # Should throw an error
```

**EDIT:**

- `@staticmethod` will work on both class instances like `MyClass().test_method(args)`and just a regular direct call like `MyClass.test_method(args)`
- However a regular method(without `self` in it) can't be called on a class instance. So you will always have to call it as `MyClass.test_method(args)`

Comment: How is a normal function declared in a class different from a static method?

Comment: @Theod'Or It is identical to staticmethods, the only difference being, you can't call it on class instances.

Comment: @jar do you happen to know why Python provides these two types of static methods? (with and without decorators), e.g. what would be a good reason for restricting instance calls?

Answer (score 4):

`self` isn't necessarily required. However, if you want to reference any variable or value that is associated with the object(instantiation of the class) (E.g. for a class about cars, it's speed, self.speed) you'll need to have `self` as a parameter in the function. For this reason, it's common practice to always have self as an argument, otherwise you aren't really using the class for the right reason.

EDIT:
This will actually throw an error if you do the following:

```
class a():
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.asd = x
    def hello(x):
        print(x)

>>> g = a(4)
>>> g.hello(5)
```

as when calling "hello", both "self" and "4" will be passed as parameters. It would work in the following instance, which is what I was saying above:

```
>>> g = a
>>> g.hello(4)
```

or

```
>>> a.hello(4)
```

Comment: This isn't really true. `self` *is* required for an instance method, even if you don't use it,  because it will be passed anyway; if the method doesn't accept it, you will get a TypeError.

Comment: Can you give me an example of some code that throws this error? Because the following:
`class a():

 def hello(x):

  print(x)`

works fine

Comment: `a.hello()` would work, but then you're not calling it on an instance so you wouldn't expect to have `self` anyway. `a().hello()` would give that error.

Comment: You're right, I just tested it. That's really interesting, learn something new every day (:

Answer (score 1):

To add on to the existing answers here and provide a code example:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def myStaticMethod():
        print("a static method")

    @staticmethod
    def myStaticMethodWithArg(my_arg):
        print(my_arg)
        print("a static method")


MyClass.myStaticMethod()
MyClass.myStaticMethodWithArg("skhsdkj")
abc = MyClass()
abc.myStaticMethodWithArg("avc")
```

Try removing the `@staticmethod` decorator and rerunning the code and see what happens! (The very last call will fail since the method is passed in both `self` and the string input. By adding the decorator, we can guide the interpreter to perform our desired action)