# Issue running self objects in mqtt paho callback function

Tags: python, oop, mqtt, paho

I'm trying to write a script that saves mqtt data and sends it to influxDB. The issue I'm having is that the callback function of the mqtt-paho module keeps giving the error:
`AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'write_api'`. I think this is because of the `self` in the internal 'Client' class of the mqtt-paho. My full script can be found below:

```
# Imported modules 
# standard time module
from datetime import datetime
import time
# InfluxDB specific modules 
from influxdb_client import InfluxDBClient, Point, WritePrecision
from influxdb_client.client.write_api import SYNCHRONOUS

#MQTT paho specific modules
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt



class data_handler(): # Default namespaces are just for all the ESPs.


    def __init__(self, namespace_list=["ESP01","ESP02","ESP03","ESP04","ESP05","ESP06","ESP07","ESP08"]):
        
        # initialize influxdb client and define access token and data bucket
        token = "XXXXXXXXXX" # robotlab's token
        self.org = "Home"   
        self.bucket = "HomeSensors"
        self.flux_client = InfluxDBClient(url="http://localhost:8086", token=token)
        self.write_api = self.flux_client.write_api(write_options=SYNCHRONOUS)
        
        # Initialize and establish connection to MQTT broker 
        broker_address="XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX"
        self.mqtt_client = mqtt.Client("influx_client") #create new instance
        self.mqtt_client.on_message=data_handler.mqtt_message #attach function to callback
        self.mqtt_client.connect(broker_address) #connect to broker

        # Define list of namespaces
        self.namespace_list = namespace_list
        print(self.namespace_list)


    def mqtt_message(self, client, message):
        print("message received " ,str(message.payload.decode("utf-8")))
        print("message topic=",message.topic)
        print("message qos=",message.qos)
        print("message retain flag=",message.retain)
        
        sequence = [message.topic, message.payload.decode("utf-8")]
        self.write_api.write(self.bucket, self.org, sequence)

    def mqtt_listener(self):

        for namespace in self.namespace_list:
            self.mqtt_client.loop_start() #start the loop
            print("Subscribing to topics!")
            message = namespace+"/#"
            self.mqtt_client.subscribe(message, 0)
            time.sleep(4) # wait
            self.mqtt_client.loop_stop() #stop the loop


def main():
    influxHandler = data_handler(["ESP07"])
    influxHandler.mqtt_listener()

if  __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The code works fine until I add `self.someVariable` in the callback function. What would be a good way to solve this problem? I don't really want to be making global variables hence why I chose to use a class.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dealing with `self` when there are multiple classes involved can get confusing. The paho library calls `on_message` [as follows](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.python/blob/9782ab81fe7ee3a05e74c7f3e1d03d5611ea4be4/src/paho/mqtt/client.py#L3570):

```py
on_message(self, self._userdata, message)
```

So the first argument passed is the instance of [`Client`](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.python/blob/9782ab81fe7ee3a05e74c7f3e1d03d5611ea4be4/src/paho/mqtt/client.py#L3570) so what you are seeing is expected (in the absence of any classes).

If the callback is a [method object](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#method-objects) (which appears to be your aim) "the instance object is passed as the first argument of the function". This means your function would take four arguments and the definition be:

```py
mqtt_message(self, client, userdata, msg)
```

Based upon this you might expect your application to fail earlier than it is but lets look at how you are setting the callback:

```py
self.mqtt_client.on_message=data_handler.mqtt_message
```

`datahandler` is the class itself, not an instance of the class. This means you are effectively setting the callback to a static function (with no binding to any instance of the class - [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43587154/11810946) might help). You need to change this to:

```py
self.mqtt_client.on_message=self.mqtt_message
```

However this will not work as the method currently only takes three arguments; update the definition to:

```py
def mqtt_message(self, client, userdata, msg)
```

with those changes I believe this will work (or at least you will find another issue :-) ).

[An example](https://code.labstack.com/F99EoOKE) might be a better way to explain this:

```py
class mqtt_sim():
  def __init__(self):
    self._on_message = None
    
  @property
  def on_message(self):
     return self._on_message
      
  @on_message.setter
  def on_message(self, func):
    self._on_message = func

# This is what you are doing    
class data_handler1(): # Default namespaces are just for all the ESPs.
   def __init__(self):
      self.mqtt = mqtt_sim()      
      self.mqtt.on_message = data_handler1.mqtt_message    # xxxxx         
   def mqtt_message(self, client, message):        
      print("mqtt_message1", self, client, message) 

# This is what you should be doing      
class data_handler2(): # Default namespaces are just for all the ESPs.
   def __init__(self):
      self.mqtt = mqtt_sim()      
      self.mqtt.on_message = self.mqtt_message #attach function to callback             
   def mqtt_message(self, mqttself, client, message):        
      print("mqtt_message2", self, mqttself, client, message)    

# Lets try using both of the above      
d = data_handler1()
d.mqtt._on_message("self", "userdata", "message")

d = data_handler2()
d.mqtt._on_message("self", "userdata", "message")
```