# writing command line for class methods using python and typer

Tags: python, command-line-interface, typer

I'm using [image: Typer logo] [**Typer**](https://typer.tiangolo.com/) to write a command line program using python.

#### Code

Here's an example script of were I'm running into trouble.

```
import typer

app = typer.Typer()

@app.command()
def hello(name):
    typer.echo(f'Hello!')

@app.command()
def goodbye():
    typer.echo(f'Goodbye.')

class Grettings:

    @app.command()
    def aloha(self):
        typer.echo('Aloha!')

    @app.command()
    def bonjour(self):
        typer.echo('Bonjour!')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app()
```

When the following commands are entered into the terminal the expected output is given.

```bash
python main.py hello   
python main.py goodbye
```

#### Issue

However, when the class methods are called, I get the following exception.

```
python main.py aloha  
python main.py bonjour

    Usage: main.py aloha [OPTIONS] SELF
    Try 'main.py aloha --help' for help.
    
    Error: Missing argument 'SELF'.
```

Clearly, this is from the class not being initialized, yet. But it seems like it'd be a common problem, so I assume there's a simple solution to the issue.

#### Research

Possible solutions I've found include using decorators on the class/methods being used, or using a special class that'd need to be inherited to "expose" the class methods.

Hint from [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47371003/5730279) of [Can a decorator of an instance method access the class?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2366713/5730279) :

> Any decorator is called BEFORE class is built, so is unknown to the decorator.

Comment: Make it a static method, then it doesn't need a class instance.

Comment: It's not a particularly sensible thing to do.  `typer` would have to know how to create an instance of the class, when that's really your job.  All you need is a short shim method: `@app.command` / `def aloha():` /  `Grettings().aloha()` .

Comment: Terminology note, these are not "class methods". They are instance methods

Comment: I would posit the best solution here is to *simply not make those functions methods*, and define them at the module level

Answer (score 4):

#### Issue with decorated instance methods

*Typer* tries to invoke the callback as `Grettings().aloha()`.
This will fail in Python with error:

> TypeError: hallo() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

#### Demo of command invocation in *Typer*

See following demo recorded in Python shell:

Part 1:  How it works (with static functions, no self argument)

```
>>> import typer
>>> app = typer.Typer()
>>> app
<typer.main.Typer object at 0x7f0713f59c18>
>>> app.__dict__
{'_add_completion': True, 'info': <typer.models.TyperInfo object at 0x7f0713f59c50>, 'registered_groups': [], 'registered_commands': [], 'registered_callback': None}
>>> @app.command()
... def hello():
...     typer.echo('hello')
... 
>>> app.__dict__['registered_commands']
[<typer.models.CommandInfo object at 0x7f0711e69cf8>]
>>> app.__dict__['registered_commands'][0].cls
<class 'typer.core.TyperCommand'>
>>> app.__dict__['registered_commands'][0].callback
<function hello at 0x7f070f539378>
>>> app.__dict__['registered_commands'][0].callback()
hello
```

Part 2: How it wont work (with instance methods, self argument required)

```
>>> class German:
...     @app.command()
...     def hallo(self):
...         typer.echo('Hallo')
... 
>>> app.__dict__['registered_commands'][1]
<typer.models.CommandInfo object at 0x7f070f59ccf8>
>>> app.__dict__['registered_commands'][1].callback
<function German.hallo at 0x7f070f539158>
>>> app.__dict__['registered_commands'][1].callback()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: hallo() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
>>> app.__dict__['registered_commands'][1].callback(German())
Hallo
```

Note: In the last statement I a fresh instance was passed as argument `self` to the callback and the invocation succeeded with expected output.

#### Fixed code

I changed 3 things:

1. Renamed your class `Grettings` into `Greetings` (spelling)
2. Redefined the 2 existing methods as static class methods like [Barmar's comment suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70793842/writing-command-line-for-class-methods-using-python-and-typer#comment125153146_70793842).
3. Additionally I added a new instance method `nihao(self)` to demonstrate the failure.

```py
import typer

app = typer.Typer()


@app.command()
def hello(name):
    typer.echo(f'Hello!')

@app.command()
def goodbye():
    typer.echo(f'Goodbye.')

class Greetings:
    @app.command()
    def aloha():              # function or class-method (implicitly static)
        typer.echo('Aloha!')

    @staticmethod             # explicitly static
    @app.command()
    def bonjour():            # no self argument!
        typer.echo('Bonjour!')

    @app.command()
    def nihao(self):          # callback invocation fails because missing self argument
        typer.echo('Nihao!')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app()
```

#### Behavior and output as expected

Although the offered commands still list `nihao` as available, the invocation of it will fail equally as you experienced.

But the command-decorated static methods can be invoked  now.

```sh
$ python3 SO_typer.py --help
Usage: SO_typer.py [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...

Options:
  --install-completion [bash|zsh|fish|powershell|pwsh]
                                  Install completion for the specified shell.
  --show-completion [bash|zsh|fish|powershell|pwsh]
                                  Show completion for the specified shell, to
                                  copy it or customize the installation.

  --help                          Show this message and exit.

Commands:
  aloha
  bonjour
  goodbye
  hello
  nihao
```

️ Chinese greeting fails because no argument `self` passed with invocation:

```sh
$ python3 SO_typer.py nihao
Usage: SO_typer.py nihao [OPTIONS] SELF
Try 'SO_typer.py nihao --help' for help.

Error: Missing argument 'SELF'.
```

Hawaiian greeting works because static invocation possible now:

```sh
$ python3 SO_typer.py aloha
Aloha!
```

#### See also

- [Do we really need @staticmethod decorator in python to declare static method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43587044/do-we-really-need-staticmethod-decorator-in-python-to-declare-static-method)
- Click Documentation (8.0.x): [Callback Invocation](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.0.x/commands/#callback-invocation)

Answer (score 0):

The `skycaptain` was replying it - https://github.com/tiangolo/typer/issues/309#issuecomment-1934028088

I've implemented a pattern to auto get the methods that is a command.

```py
import inspect

import typer

class MyKlass:
    some_default_value: str

    def __init__(self, some_default_value: str):
        self.some_default_value = some_default_value
        self.app = typer.Typer()

        for method, _ in inspect.getmembers(self, predicate=inspect.ismethod):
            if not method.startswith('cmd'):
                continue

            cmd_name = method.strip('cmd_')
            self.app.command(
                name=cmd_name,
                help=self.some_default_value
            )(eval(f'self.{method}'))

    def cmd_run(self):
        print("Running")

    def cmd_sleep(self):
        print("sleep")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyKlass(some_default_value="it's a command").app()
```

```bash
Usage: python -m legalops_commons.utils.foo [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...

Options:
  --install-completion  Install completion for the current shell.
  --show-completion     Show completion for the current shell, to copy it or
                        customize the installation.
  --help                Show this message and exit.

Commands:
  run    it's a command
  sleep  it's a command
```