# Is `self` actually mandatory for class methods in Python?

Tags: python

I saw a code snippet in Python 3.6.5 that can be replicated with this simplified example below and I do not understand if this is something concerning or not. I am surprised it works honestly...

```py
class Foo:

    def bar(numb):
        return numb

    A1 = bar(1)


print(Foo)
print(Foo.A1)
print(Foo.bar(17))
```

In all python guides that I have seen, `self` appears as the first argument for all the purposes we know and love. When it is not, the methods are decorated with a static decorator and all is well. This case works as it is, however. If I were to use the static decorator on `bar`, I get a `TypeError` when setting `A1`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/dir/understanding_classes.py", line 1, in <module>
    class Foo:
  File "/home/user/dir/understanding_classes.py", line 7, in Foo
    A1 = bar(1)
TypeError: 'staticmethod' object is not callable
```

Is this something that is OK keeping in the code or is this a potential problem? I hope the question is not too broad, but how and why does this work?

Comment: I think you can read about the differences between programming with oop and functions. Regards.

Comment: it would also work if you named the param as `self` instead, looks like.

Comment: What are you annotating with `@staticmethod` here?

Comment: however, I am unable to reproduce this on my machine. If i add static method code runs fine on my end at least.

Comment: @RyanHaining, sorry for not being specific. Decorating `bar`. Will updated the comment.

Comment: correct, I am able to reproduce this error on version Python `3.7.13`. I think I was trying on Python 3.10 earlier.

Comment: @rv.kvetch, I used Python 3.6.5

Comment: When I try to reproduce, I get the same results with and without `@staticmethod` on Python 3.10.3, at least for the tests you've posted. I do *not* get the TypeError unless I try to access the method from an _instance_ rather than from the _class_ as you have shown.  See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43587044/do-we-really-need-staticmethod-decorator-in-python-to-declare-static-method

Comment: You never call the function as a *bound instance method*, so it never receives an implicit first instance argument. If you instantiated the class and called the method there, you would…

Comment: No, you should not do this (even though you can)

Comment: @SarahMesser this issue is only reproducible in Python 3.6 and 3.7, if I understand it. I used `pyenv` for switching py versions to test it out.

Comment: The reason for defining instance methods this way has to do with the [descriptor protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html). Understand that, and you'll know why you need an additional parameter (called whatever you like; "self" is conventional but not required) for it to work properly.

Comment: `staticmethod` is just a type that provides a *different* definition of `__get__` than the function type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first parameter of the method will be set to the receiver. We call it `self` by convention, but `self` isn't a keyword; any valid parameter name would work just as well.

There's two different ways to invoke a method that are relevant here. Let's say we have a simple `Person` class with a `name` and a `say_hi` method

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def say_hi(self):
        print(f'Hi my name is {self.name}')


p = Person('J.K.')
```

If we call the method on `p`, we'll get a call to `say_hi` with `self=p`

```
p.say_hi() # self=p, prints 'Hi my name is J.K.'
```

What you're doing in your example is calling the method via the class, and passing that first argument explicitly. The equivalent call here would be

```
Person.say_hi(p) # explicit self=p, also prints 'Hi my name is J.K.'
```

In your example you're using a non-static method then calling it through the class, *then* explicitly passing the first parameter. It happens to work but it doesn't make a lot of sense because you should be able to invoke a non-static method by saying

```
f = Foo()
f.bar() # numb = f, works, but numb isn't a number it's a Foo
```

If you want to put a function inside of a class that doesn't have a receiver, that's when you want to use `@staticmethod` (or, `@classmethod` more often)

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def say_hi(self):
        print(f'Hi my name is {self.name}')

    @staticmethod
    def say_hello():
        print('hello')


p = Person('J.K.')

Person.say_hello()
p.say_hello()
```

Comment: Hope not to bother, but could you elaborate about what is happening when I set `A1`? Is this something that is a sensible thing to do or should `bar` simply be a separate method?

Comment: `A1` is defined at the class-level, so regardless of how many `Foo`s you create, you always just have a single `A1`. There are legitimate reasons to do this, it's hard to guess without more information, but if your intention is that each `Foo` instance has it's own `A1`, then you should change your code to set `self.A1` in `__init__` like I did with the `Person`'s `self.name`

Comment: Sorry, I see I was not specific with my question. I am more interested if it is OK that `A1` is created by calling `bar`, which is in turn a method of questionable utility, i.e. `A1 = bar(1)`. Thank you kindly for your patience and your time.

Comment: @J.K. it would make sense if `bar` were a `@staticmethod`, which you should be able to add without a problem. I don't know what you're doing that's giving you that error. I was able to add `@staticmethod` without a problem (like others are saying).